# Why this code is not working (if-statement)

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators

Why "if" is not accepting the condition (both "x" and "n" are constants after all).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int x,n;
scanf("%d %d",&x,&n)
if(x==(4n-3))
printf("%d",x);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that it even compiles. You are missing a `;` at the end of the `scanf` line (and there's also the problem that @ram mentions in the answer below).

Comment: Please don't edit the code to "fix" bugs as they are pointed out. It turns posted answers obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

Compile and you get this:

```
error: expected ';' before 'if'
4 | scanf("%d %d",&x,&n)
  |                     ^
  |                     ;
```

The little `^` points out the exact location of the bug and tells you to write a semi colon there. Go to that location that the compiler points out and do as it says.

Then:

```
error: invalid suffix "n" on integer constant
5 | if(x==(4n-3))
```

This means that `4n` is nonsense, it is not valid C. You need to write `4*n-3`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't writing a math statement here
It should be `if(x==(4*n-3))`